# Multi thread Web API application

Tags: c#, multithreading, iis, asp.net-web-api, performance-testing

I have a C# Web API application with a react front end. Most of the front end pages call multiple API's on load. The performance and response times of each individual API is quite fast and good enough for my application. However, when I test the application, page load times take longer and longer as I add more users. I assume this is because there are more requests coming in than IIS can handle e.g. all its threads are busy so it is taking longer to process each request.

Given this, the solution seems to be to reduce the number of requests coming in. I can do this by combining the page load calls for each page into single calls, then retrieve all the required data in one. This would mean that each individual piece of data would be obtained synchronously, slowing down response times again. Given this, it seems it would be best to multi thread the combined API calls so the whole request would only take as long as the longest request.

In summary, the problem seems to be that requests were slow as IIS was running out of threads to process the requests. The solution is to make single API calls that are multi threaded.

My question is, would moving the extra thread demand from IIS to the C# application not be just moving the same problem to a different place? Eg are the IIS and C# threads derived from the same resource?

Comment: This is extremely hard to answer without knowing what wild and wonderful things you are doing and how you are doing them. Can you be more concise with your performance results, architecture, code sample, profiling results. Otherwise this ends up as way too broad

Comment: Did you try profiling your API code? If you're running a semi-recent version of IIS and your code is not _extremely_ streamlined and optimized, I would see it as unlikely that IIS threading is the limitation. At least my first guess wouldn't be there.

Comment: As suggested this seems like it could be a coding issue rather than a thread issue. I've built API's that are used by SPA's that do a similar thing, multiple requests per page and IIS serves thousands of users with no problem. Wrapping up many requests into one will only really take away the overhead of establishing a HTTP call, the underlying work will still be the same. Caching could also be your friend (and your enemy!!)

Comment: another possibility is that as data grows in your database, it exposes the inefficiency of your queries to that data. It would be a good idea to keep track of how long execution of your queries is taking... individually.